# Anaconda distribution and Windows 32-bit

Tags: anaconda

I'm trying to develop Python applications related to machive learning, neural networks, etc. under Windows 7 (32-bit)

Why does Anaconda distribution for Windows 32-bit not contain PyTorch, TensorFlow and Keras?

Answer (score 0):

Those packages are not included in installer https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.7_win-32/ you have to install them. Make sure you create an environment first https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow